# Rotate svg from maps does not work

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, svg, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to apply a `rotation` to an `svg` type icon but it's not applying correctly, actually nothing fashions in the icon.

I'm doing it this way:

1. First I'm initializing the google maps variable like this:

   ```
   marker: any = new google.maps.Marker;
   ```
2. Then I run the function to create the marker like this:

   ```
   createMarker (location) {
     if (this.marker) {
       this.marker.setMap (null);
     }

     this.marker.setPosition (new google.maps.LatLng (location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude));
     this.marker.setMap (this.map);

     const icon = {
       url: 'assets / bus.svg',
       anchor: new google.maps.Point (0, 0),
       scaledSize: new google.maps.Size (32, 32)
     };

     this.marker.setIcon (icon);
     this.map.setCenter (new google.maps.LatLng (location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude));
   }
   ```
3. And when I move the `marker` that comes a new location I do so:

   ```
   moveMarker (location) {
     if (this.marker) {
       const currentPos = this.marker.getPosition ();
       const nextPos = new google.maps.LatLng (location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
       const duration = this.calcMoveDuration (location.distanceFilter, location.coords.speed);

       console.log ('currentPos', currentPos)
       console.log ('next', nextPos)

       let fraction = 0;
       const steps = 30;
       const fractionStep = 1 / steps;
       let animateTimer = setInterval (() => {
         fraction + = fractionStep;
         const interpolate = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate (currentPos, nextPos, fraction);
         const icon = {
           url: 'assets / bus.svg',
           scaledSize: new google.maps.Size (32, 32),
           anchor: new google.maps.Point (0, 0),
           rotation: 50
         };
         this.marker.setIcon (icon);

         if (fraction> = 1.0)
           clearInterval (animateTimer);
           animateTimer = null;
         }
       }, duration / steps);
     }
   }
   ```

It starts on the map but does not solve anything stays like in the image:

[image: imagem google maps]

My wish is for the bus to travel over the polyline

More details about the project:

I'm developing in angular 5 and using google maps API to create and manage my map (markers, polyline, among others), the real objective is for the bus to follow over the polyline and make the ruddy when it does so. I already tried to develop this mechanism with a png image, SVG but none of it is giving to apply the rotate in the image.

I searched for some things on the internet however the things I found will not help me solve the problem, I saw a possibility to run the image with css but all the applications are related to jquery none of them with typescript so I am not able to apply this option to check if with or without the bus moving on the polyline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Marker icons can not be rotated. Use `Symbol` for that ([docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols)), it has required property `path`, just pass the svg path directly as a string, not as a file.
2. Use css to rotate image.

Smth like this. Remember, that icons can have different "zero" angle. Your bus being not rotated can be directed to the North, to the East etc., so you just add or substract initial angle.

```
$('img[src="' + iconurl + '"]').css({
     'transform': 'rotate(' + (heading - initial) + 'deg)'
});
```

Comment: I have multiple markers and need to rotate them. If I add them one by one it is ok to access latest marker in the DOM and assign an attribute to access later on. But if I add them in a loop I cant get latest one because of the async addition.. How can I handle this.

Comment: @freezer simple hack is to use different urls for icons. Just add `?id=IDhere` to icon url and you can access it via `$('img[src="' + iconurl + '?id='+ID+'"]').css({
     'transform': 'rotate(' + (heading - initial) + 'deg)'
});`